# Screen became flickry after trying to install Linux Mint

Tags: linux, windows-10, linux-mint

So I tried to install Linux on an external hard drive. After I booted the system from the external drive to install linux, one of my screen started flickering. So I decided to postpone the process and just shut down and go back to my windows 10. Surprisingly, after a normal boot to windows 10 ( and unplugging my external drive) the screen kept flickering.. not only that, but also, I can still see the icons of the linux mint (barely) in the background!

I tried all the usuals from restarting to unplugging the screen ...etc. Every time now I login to Windows, I can still see the Linux mint and icons slightly in the background, and the screen is still flickering.

Here is an image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't sound like a problem with Linux, or Windows for that matter. More a problem with your screen. A fix may include just turning the screen off for a few hours, or putting on some [static](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfycQJrzXCA) for a while in an effort to 'clear' the screen.

[Source with more information](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/why-do-images-get-burned-into-lcd-and-plasma-displays-and-how-you-can-fix-it/)